# authentication error trying to initiate replica set in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to initiate a mongodb replica set from a python script, and running into an error with authentication.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

ip = 'zzz.zz.zzz.zz'
port = 27017
replica_set = 'yomama'

config = {
  '_id': replica_set,
  'members': [
    {'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx',
     '_id': 0,
     'arbiterOnly': False},
    {'host': 'yyy.yy.yyy.yy',
     '_id': 1,
     'arbiterOnly': False},
    {'host': 'zzz.zz.zzz.zz',
     '_id': 2,
     'arbiterOnly': False},
  ],
}

connection = MongoClient(ip, port)
connection.admin.command('replSetInitiate', config)
```

Running this script results in:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('replSetInitiate', {'_id': 'yomama', 'members': [{'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx', '_id': 0, 'arbiterOnly': False}, {'host': 'yyy.yy.yyy.yy', '_id': 1, 'arbiterOnly': False}, {'host': 'zzz.zz.zzz.zz', '_id': 2, 'arbiterOnly': False}]})])
failed: unauthorized
```

There is no authentication set up on the database, and running the same thing from a mongo shell works fine:

```
db.runCommand({replSetInitiate:{'_id': 'yomama', 'members': [{'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx', '_id': 0, 'arbiterOnly': false}, {'host': 'yyy.yy.yyy.yy', '_id': 1, 'arbiterOnly': false}, {'host': 'zzz.zz.zzz.zz', '_id': 2, 'arbiterOnly': false}]}})
{
    "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Any thoughts on why this error when doing the same thing with pymongo?

Comment: i'm confused, your response makes me think that you did have authentication set up? i'm actually trying to do something similar so i'm just wondering if you did or did not have authentication setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This was happening because by specifying the ip and port while initializing MongoClient (`connection = MongoClient(ip, port)`), the client did not bypass authentication using the [localhost exception](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#localhost-exception). Initializing using localhost does the trick, e.g. `connection = MongoClient()`.